# JavaScript fetch returns TypeError: NetworkError

Tags: javascript, weather-api

I made a small weather app. It uses the following JS code to get the weather data from weatherapi.com. This worked perfectly fine. I was changing some values in my CSS when it suddenly stopped working. I tried undoing the changes to the CSS, but it didn't fix the problem. I am quite new to web development, so I don't know what caused this issue. I checked the api website, and I am far under my limit (4.9 million calls under).

Full error:

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. weather.js:121:17
    getWeatherData http://127.0.0.1:5500/scripts/weather.js:121
    (Async: promise callback)
    getWeatherData http://127.0.0.1:5500/scripts/weather.js:120
    onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html:1
```

DevTools say `NS_BINDING_ABORTED`

The code (apiKey excluded):

```js
function getWeatherData() {
    let query = document.getElementById("location-input").value;
    fetch(`https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${apiKey}&q=${query}`)
    .then(function(respone) {
        return respone.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        if (loadedCities.includes(data.location.name)) {return;}

        loadedCities.push(data.location.name)
        document.getElementById("weather-grid").innerHTML += `<div class="weather-item">
            <img src="../svg/${data.current.is_day == 1 ? weatherIconsDay[data.current.condition.code] : weatherIconsNight[data.current.condition.code]}.svg" class="weather-icon">
            <p class="text weather-city">${data.location.name}</p>
            <p class="text weather-condition">${data.current.condition.text}</p>
            <p class="text weather-condition">${data.current.temp_c}&degC</p>
        </div`
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    });
}

// Clear input form
document.getElementById("location-input").value = "";

var loadedCities = [];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="input-container">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <input id="location-input" type="text" class="text location-input" placeholder="Search">
            <input onclick="getWeatherData()" type="submit" class="text search-button" value="Search">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </form>

        <div class="weather-grid" id="weather-grid"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/weather.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried printing the url before running fetch and manually accessing it using Firefox, which worked without problem.
I made sure that apiKey, query and all other variables are valid. `weatherIconsDay` and `weatherIconsNight` are two very long json objects that map the codes to the correct images. I exluded them for readability.

EDIT:
When changing the form element to a div element, it works without problem. I originally used a div, but then changed to using a form to submit the form when pressing enter.

Comment: That error is very very broad. Can you include the full error? Perhaps your internet connection is unstable...

Comment: @code Yes of course. Here is the full message: `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource. weather.js:121:17
    getWeatherData http://127.0.0.1:5500/scripts/weather.js:121
    (Async: promise callback)
    getWeatherData http://127.0.0.1:5500/scripts/weather.js:120
    onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html:1
`
My internet can't be the problem, as the fetch always works when using my browser. It was also working just a few minutes ago without any problems. This is the first time I encountered such a problem.

Comment: Check your browser's DevTools console. Fetch errors that are returned to JavaScript code are deliberately vague (to prevent malicious code from, e.g., mapping your network), but the DevTools should have more information.

Comment: @JoshKelley It doesn't really give me a lot more information, except for an error saying `NS_BINDING_ABORTED`.

Comment: When using the Debugger function, it shows an error in a file called inject.js, on a line saying `nodecrypto = require('crypto');`.

Comment: @Skratymir Please do not add details in comments. When people as for the full error, or code improvements, etc. [edit] your post to [put those missing bits of information in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Yogi that is the same data I get when querying for Rome. It works when I exchange the form element with a div, but I don't know why using a form is a problem.

Comment: @Yogi is there a way I can prevent the page from reloading?

Comment: @Yogi Thanks a lot! Adding `onsubmit=event.preventDefault()` to the form fixed it. Adding `onsubmit="return false"` also worked, but I assume that that would be a suboptimal solution. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the page reloading when submitting the form, and therefore cancelling the api request. Adding `onsubmit="event.preventDefault()"` to the form element fixed the problem. For anyone having the same problem, here is the full final html for reference:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="input-container" onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <input id="location-input" type="text" class="text location-input" placeholder="Search">
            <input onclick="getWeatherData()" type="submit" class="text search-button" value="Search">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </form>

        <div class="weather-grid" id="weather-grid"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/weather.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```